# Correct approach to specific style code for small and big iOS screen in React Native?

Tags: ios, react-native, styles

Is there an easy way to make a different style (like smaller and bigger buttons etc. ) for small size ios devices and the big ones in React Native? Like here (https://reactnative.dev/docs/platform-specific-code#platform-specific-extensions) when I need different styles for a specific platform iOS and Android in React Native?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All is explained in your link.

Two solutions:

1. One component where you handle the platform

:

```
import { Platform } from 'react-native';

...

<Button style={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? styles.iosButton: styles.androidButton} />
```

2. Two components for each platforms

:

```
BigButton.ios.js
BigButton.android.js

...

import BigButton from './BigButton';
```

Importing like this will load the correct component depending of the platform

To adjust depending of the screen size you can use Dimensions

```
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native';

const windowWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;

<View style={windowWidth > 1200 ? styles.big_screen : styles.small_screen}>
    ...
</View>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! Maybe I miswrote my question. I need something like in the link - [link](https://reactnative.dev/docs/platform-specific-code#platform-specific-extensions), but for differences between iPhone 5S (small screen ) and iPhone XS (big screen).

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try it!